# PHP file in www dir can't access images in user dir

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have a PHP file in my var/www directory and I want it to read images from the /user/folder/folder directory. I have tried creating a soft link to the user folder, however, nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. To note, my permissions for dir and all files is set to 755 and the user and group are set to my username (pass required for access).

```js
$files = glob("~user/downloads/other/*.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine when you include the full file path.  Not sure what OS you're on, but should be similar to `glob("/Users/yourusername/downloads/*.*");`